# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property ' ' of undefined

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to make a form field to add new hotel and specify the address.
I have the hotel class:

```
export class Hotel {

  public constructor (
    public name:string,
    public address: Address,
  ){}
}

export class Address {
    country:string;  
    town :string;
    street: string;
}
```

this's the function `addHotel` in the component:

```
addHotel(hotel:any, address:any){
  if (this.form.valid) {
    let newHotel = new Hotel(hotel["name"], (hotel.address["country"], hotel.address["town"], hotel.address["street"]));
```

the html form is very simple:

```
<div class="tab-pane" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="text-gray">Name :</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></div>
            <input formControlName="name" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="address">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="text-gray">Country :</label>
        <div class="input-group" >
            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></div>
            <input  class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <label class="text-gray">Town :</label>
        <div class="input-group" >
            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-map"></i></div>
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>

        <label class="text-gray">Street :</label>
        <div class="input-group" >
            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-map-signs"></i></div>
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I even tried to add new function, `addAddress`:

```
addAddress(hotel,address):any{
    //let newAddress = new Address(hotel.address["country"], ,hotel.address["town"], hotel.address["street"]);
    this.address.push(hotel.address["country"], hotel.address["town"], hotel.address["street"]);
    console.log(this.address);
    return this.address;
  }
```

but it always return empty array {country:null, town:null, street:null}
or the famous error: **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'country' of undefined**

Comment: In addAddress(), put in console.log()'s before the push to see what hotel and address are composed like.

Comment: @rrd   console.log(this.address) return [] 0:undefined 1:undefined 2:undefined
length:3

Comment: updated my answer with working code please have a look

Comment: updated may answer check , you are lacking binding so you need to do it you can go to `angular.io` portal for gettting detail

Answer (score 2):

Use the safe navigation operator (?)

look like this

```
<p>Employer: {{address?.country}}</p>
```

> The safe navigation operator (?) means that the employer field is
>   optional and if undefined, the rest of the expression should be
>   ignored.

Reference
https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet

Answer (score 0):

Read this post it having all details you want : https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#nested-formgroups

Please define binding between template and typescript for getting value from template form control example :

```
export class etailComponent5 {
  hotelForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.hotelForm= this.fb.group({ // <-- the parent FormGroup
      name: [''],
      address: this.fb.group({ // <-- the child FormGroup
        street: '',
        town: '',
        country: ''
      })
    });
  }

  saveform() {
    const hotel:Hotel = hotelForm.value;
   //or to get individual control you need to do like this 
   // const street= hotelForm.get('address.street').value
   // const town= hotelForm.get('address.town').value
   // const coutnry= hotelForm.get('address.country').value
  }
}
```

---

```
<form [formGroup]="hotelForm" >
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="center-block">Name:
        <input class="form-control" formControlName="name">
      </label>
  </div>
        <div formGroupName="address" class="well well-lg">
          <h4>Secret Lair</h4>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="center-block">Street:
              <input class="form-control" formControlName="street">
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="center-block">Town:
              <input class="form-control" formControlName="town">
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="center-block">Country:
              <input class="form-control" formControlName="country">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

---

Working :

```
const address = new Address();
address.country='abc';
address.street= 'abc';
address.town ='abc';
let newHotel = new Hotel('abc', address);
console.log(newHotel.name);
console.log(`${newHotel.address.country},${newHotel.address.street},${newHotel.address.town}`);
```

As per you structure `address - property` is class used in `hotel`, so you need to initialized it and then you can assign to address property. as given in above code..

In your code you are trying to set value without initializing it

---

I suggest make use of interface instead of class

```
    export interface Hotel {
       name:string;
       address: Address;
    }

    export interface Address {
        country:string;  
        town :string;
        street: string;
    }

const hotel: Hotel  = { name: 'name of hotel',
                        address: { country:'abc', town : 'abc', city:'abc' } 
                      };
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i get  {country: null, town: null, street: null}

Comment: @afef - try out interface way will resolve issue, which one you tried is not working ?

Comment: new Address() in the constructor

Comment: country, street, town should take the value given in the add form. when I initialise address.country:'abc', country take 'abc'.

Answer (score 0):

even when I add  `console.log(address.town);` to the addAddress function, I get **undefined**. what I have to do??